# How to inject a request scoped provider at NestJS controller?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I have a request scoped injectable for logging.

f.e.

```js
import { Injectable, Scope } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export class RequestLogger {
  public log(message: string) {
    console.log(message);
  }
}
```

(disregard for a moment that it doesn't use a constructor with the request yet; that's beside the point)

And I also have a controller with some singleton injections.

I'd like to inject the request injectable in a way that will allow the controller to be initiated just once. Injecting it at the constructor will make the controller be recreated on each request, so surely that's not the way (is it?).

I tried to place it in the method signature, but that doesn't seem to do anything.

e.g.

```js
@Controller('register')
export class RegisterApiController {
  public constructor(
    private readonly registerService: RegisterService,
  ) {
    console.log('Controller initiated');
  }

  @Post()
  public async postIndex(
    @Inject(RequestLogger) logger: RequestLogger,
  ): Promise<unknown> {
    console.log('request made');
    logger.log('Logger message to log');

    return this.registerService.register();
  }
}
```

after application bootstrap (that also includes "Controller initiated"), each request terminates with error 500, and in the console

```sh
Request made
[TypeError] Cannot read property 'log' of undefined
```

Is there a way to inject a request scoped injectable without forcing a recreation of the controller that uses it? What is it?

If there isn't another way, is there at least a way to move initial controller logic somewhere else, so that what needs to be done once on first controller init can be done there?

Comment: I ended up doing a custom decorator, combined with an interceptor. The interceptor puts the new logger in the request (unconditionally, because I want to log every request anyway), and the decorator gets it from the request (enabling additional logs within the controller handler).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With nestjs, unfortunately, this is not possible, see the [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/injection-scopes#scope-hierarchy):

> Scope bubbles up the injection chain. A controller that depends on a
>   request-scoped provider will, itself, be request-scoped.

---

You can, however, inject the *initial controller logic* into the controller as a singleton, so that it won't be executed again for every request.

Answer (score 5):

This is possible with the library I've created recently, which it's free from bubbles up injection chain and performance issues:

https://github.com/kugacz/nj-request-scope

After register `RequestScopeModule` in your module class:

```
import { RequestScopeModule } from 'nj-request-scope';

@Module({
    imports: [RequestScopeModule],
})
```

your example request-scope `RequestLogger` class would look like this:

```
import { Injectable, Scope } from '@nestjs/common';
import { RequestScope } from 'nj-request-scope';

@Injectable()
@RequestScope()
export class RequestLogger {
  public log(message: string) {
    console.log(message);
  }
}
```

and in your example controller, add the class field `logger`.
The `logger` field will be a new `RequestLogger` instance created for every request without recreating a new instance of RegisterApiController.

```
@Controller('register')
export class RegisterApiController {
  public constructor(
    private readonly registerService: RegisterService,
    private readonly logger: RequestLogger,
  ) {
    console.log('Controller initiated');
  }

  @Post()
  public async postIndex(): Promise<unknown> {
    console.log('request made');
    logger.log('Logger message to log');

    return this.registerService.register();
  }
}
```

Another example you can find here: https://github.com/kugacz/nj-request-scope-example/tree/main/src/request.scope

Comment: This sounds buggy or at the very least, too hacky. I would expect any class (including controllers) in a DI framework to be constructed every time one of its injected values changes (which should be never). At the same time, I would not expect a class to be recreated just for a method call inside the class. Request specific injections to an otherwise server wide controller should be passed into the method arguments somehow IMO.

Comment: This solution is similar to the Java Spring DI request scope mechanism, which I wouldn't consider buggy or hacky. Spring also uses a Proxy Pattern for request scope injections.
Request scope DI usage in my library, NestJS and Java Spring is almost the same and I would call it the expected industry standard.
The final behavior (request scope) is exactly the same, but my library is more performant than the original NestJS solution.

Comment: I didn't look into the code too much, but if it indeed uses Spring Proxy approach, this is a recommended way of doing it, no questions asked. NestJS really made me sad. I hoped it's a wannabe Spring for JS. But it goes against some of the best features of Spring such as: Injectables are not really proxied, so you can't put a cache, or validation rules at it. All it has is an interceptor layer at the level of REST Controllers. And we all know, Controllers are just ports, not the actual API, Services are THE API

Answer (score 4):

Nestjs-pino uses async_hooks to create a request scoped logger without making the logger a request scoped provider.