# Nestjs: How to use mongoose to start a session for transaction?

Tags: mongoose, nestjs

The mongoose documentation to use a transaction is straightforward but when it is followed in nestjs, it returns an error:

```
Connection 0 was disconnected when calling `startSession`
MongooseError: Connection 0 was disconnected when calling `startSession`
    at NativeConnection.startSession
```

My code:

```
const transactionSession = await mongoose.startSession();
    transactionSession.startTransaction();

    try
    {
      const newSignupBody: CreateUserDto = {password: hashedPassword, email, username};
  
      const user: User = await this.userService.create(newSignupBody);

      //save the profile.
      const profile: Profile = await this.profileService.create(user['Id'], signupDto);

      const result:AuthResponseDto = this.getAuthUserResponse(user, profile);

      transactionSession.commitTransaction();
      return result;
    }
    catch(err)
    {
      transactionSession.abortTransaction();
    }
    finally
    {
      transactionSession.endSession();
    }
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found the solution after studying @nestjs/mongoose. The mongoose here has no connection in it. This is the reason of error being returned.

The solution:

```js
import {InjectConnection} from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
```

In the constructor of the service class, we need add connection parameter that can be used by the service.

```js
export class AuthService {
constructor(
  // other dependencies...
  @InjectConnection() private readonly connection: mongoose.Connection){}
```

Instead of

```js
const transactionSession = await mongoose.startSession();
transactionSession.startTransaction();
```

We will now use:

```js
const transactionSession = await this.connection.startSession();
transactionSession.startTransaction();
```

This way, the issue of disconnection after startSession() can be resolved.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the answer provided by Noobish I would like to demonstrate a reusable function that I use in my projects:

```ts
import { ClientSession, Connection } from 'mongoose';

export const transaction = async <T>(connection: Connection, cb: (session: ClientSession) => Promise<T>): Promise<T> => {
  const session = await connection.startSession();

  try {
    session.startTransaction();
    const result = await cb(session);
    await session.commitTransaction();
    return result;
  } catch (err) {
    await session.abortTransaction();
    throw err;
  } finally {
    await session.endSession();
  }
}
```

It can then be used i.e. like this:

```ts
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(MyModel.name) private myModel: Model<MyModelDocument>,
    @InjectConnection() private connection: Connection,
  ) {}

  async find(id: string): Promise<MyModelDocument> {
    return transaction(this.connection, async session => {
      return this.myModel
        .findOne(id)
        .session(session);
    });
  }

  async create(myDto: MyDto): Promise<MyModelDocument> {
    return transaction(this.connection, async session => {
      const newDoc = new this.myModel(myDto);
      return newDoc.save({ session });
    });
  }
```

Obviously, the above example is just for demonstration purposes in which a transaction is not necessary, since the operations are already atomic. However, one could extend the inner callback with a more complex example in which the operations would not be atomic, such as:

1. Creating a document that has a reference to a document of another schema
2. Lookup if that referenced document exists and if so, add it to an array (One-to-many relation)
3. If the referenced document doesn't exist, throw an error. This would abort the transaction and rollback all changes, such as deleting the document created in step 1. One needs to carefully specify the `session` though in all these steps

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i've done in order to manage mongoose transactions in nestjs in a way that seems clean to me.

First, create a simple abstract class that specifies the methods that should be available to manage transactions, in a generic way

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export abstract class DbSession<T> {
  public abstract start(): Promise<void>;
  public abstract commit(): Promise<void>;
  public abstract end(): Promise<void>;
  public abstract abort(): Promise<void>;
  public abstract get(): T | null;
}
```

Then you can implement special for MongoDB with mongoose

```js
import { InjectConnection } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { RequestScope } from 'nj-request-scope';

import { DbSession } from '../../abstracts';

@Injectable()
@RequestScope()
export class MongoDbSession implements DbSession<mongoose.ClientSession> {
  constructor(
    @InjectConnection()
    private readonly connection: mongoose.Connection
  ) {}

  private session: mongoose.ClientSession | null = null;

  public async start() {
    if (this.session) {
      if (this.session.inTransaction()) {
        await this.session.abortTransaction();
        await this.session.endSession();
        throw new Error('Session already in transaction');
      }
      await this.session.endSession();
    }
    this.session = await this.connection.startSession();
    this.session.startTransaction({
      readConcern: { level: 'majority' },
      writeConcern: { w: 'majority' },
      readPreference: 'primary',
      retryWrites: true,
    });
  }

  public async commit() {
    if (!this.session) {
      throw new Error('Session not started');
    }
    await this.session.commitTransaction();
  }

  public async end() {
    if (!this.session) {
      throw new Error('Session not started');
    }
    await this.session.endSession();
  }

  public async abort() {
    if (!this.session) {
      throw new Error('Session not started');
    }
    await this.session.abortTransaction();
  }

  public get() {
    return this.session;
  }
}
```

I'm using @RequestScope() because I want my singleton to have a request scope, but I don't want this scope to spread to all providers. You can read more on this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59681572/how-to-inject-a-request-scoped-provider-at-nestjs-controller) and in nj-request-scope [README](https://github.com/kugacz/nj-request-scope)

Then you can use this singleton in an interceptor.

```js
import {
  CallHandler,
  ExecutionContext,
  Injectable,
  Logger,
  NestInterceptor,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable, tap } from 'rxjs';

import { DbSession } from '../abstracts/services';

@Injectable()
export class DbSessionInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  constructor(private readonly dbSession: DbSession<unknown>) {}

  private readonly logger = new Logger(DbSessionInterceptor.name);

  async intercept(
    _: ExecutionContext,
    next: CallHandler
  ): Promise<Observable<any>> {
    await this.dbSession.start();

    return next.handle().pipe(
      tap({
        finalize: async () => {
          await this.dbSession.commit();
          await this.dbSession.end();
        },
        error: async (err: Error) => {
          await this.dbSession.abort();
          await this.dbSession.end();
          this.logger.error(err);
          throw err;
        },
      })
    );
  }
}
```

That way, if you decide to use this interceptor, then you'll have a transaction automatically created at the start of request process, and committed before sending response.

You can call this interceptor with a controller or a resolver. Below is a decorator that customizes default GraphQL resolver to imply a db transaction.

```js
import { UseInterceptors, applyDecorators } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Resolver } from '@nestjs/graphql';

import { DbSessionInterceptor } from '../abstracts';

export function ResolverWithDbSession(resolverParams?: any) {
  return applyDecorators(
    Resolver(resolverParams),
    UseInterceptors(DbSessionInterceptor)
  );
}
```

If you need to use transactions outside of request lifecycle (during fixtures operations in a `onModuleInit()` step), then you can't depend on injector. So you can create another decorator :

```js
import { Inject, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';

import { DbSession } from '../abstracts';

export function WithSessionDb() {
  const dbSessionInjector = Inject(DbSession);

  return function decorator(
    target: any,
    _propertyKey: string,
    descriptor: any // PropertyDescriptor
  ): void {
    dbSessionInjector(target, 'dbSession');
    const method = descriptor.value;
    const logger = new Logger(`${WithSessionDb.name}#${method.name}`);

    descriptor.value = async function wrapper(...args: any[]) {
      try {
        await this.dbSession.start();
        const result = await method.apply(this, args);
        await this.dbSession.commit();
        return result;
      } catch (error) {
        await this.dbSession.abort();
        logger.error(error);
        throw error;
      } finally {
        await this.dbSession.end();
      }
    };
  };
}
```

I have organized all these files in a single module called "data-services".

```js
import { Global, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { RequestScopeModule } from 'nj-request-scope';

import { MongoDbSession } from './mongo';
import { DbSession } from './abstracts';

@Global()
@Module({
  imports: [RequestScopeModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: DbSession,
      useClass: MongoDbSession,
    },
  ],
  exports: [DbSession],
})
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-extraneous-class
export class DataServicesModule {}
```

here, in this file called `data-services.module.ts`, I inject MongoDbSession instead of DbSession.

This module is declared as global, so I just have to import it in my app module.

If you need to use your session in your service,
you just have to use its provider :

```js
// ...
import { DbSession } from '../../frameworks/data-services';
// ...

@Injectable()
export class SomeRandomService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(SomeRandomModel.name)
    private readonly someRandomModel: Model<SomeRandomDocument>,
    // ...
    private readonly dbSession: DbSession<mongoose.ClientSession>
  ) {}

  
  async countRandom() {
    return this.someRandomModel.countDocuments().session(this.dbSession.get()).exec();
  }

  // ...
}
```

I hope this solution will help. It looks quite overkill, but by doing like this, you don't have to worry about transactions anymore