# NestJS onModuleInit not working when specific service is added to constructor

Tags: node.js, service, nestjs

I have a bunch of services defined in my NestJS project. Some of the services are used as common services in a lot of other services. So they are imported in a few modules as well. But I noticed that when specific service `srvD` is imported in another service `srvE2`, the `onModuleInit` is not being called when the project starts.

The project starts without any error. Not really sure what's happening.

An example of the project structure. Issue is in `srvE2`

srvA.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class SrvA {
  constructor(
    private somePkgSrv: SomePkgSrv,
  ) {}
}
```

srvB.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class SrvB {
  constructor(
    private srvA: SrvA,
  ) {}
}
```

srvC.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class SrvC {
  constructor(
    private srvA: SrvA,
    private srvB: SrvB,
  ) {}
}
```

srvD.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class SrvD {
  constructor(
    private srvA: SrvA,
    private srvB: SrvB,
    private srvC: SrvC,
  ) {}
}
```

srvD.module.ts

```
@Module({
  providers: [SrvA, SrvB, SrvC, SrvD],
  exports: [SrvD],
})
```

srvE1.ts

```
export class SrvE1 implements OnModuleInit {
  constructor(
    private srvA: SrvA,
    private srvB: SrvB,
    private srvC: SrvC,
  ) {}

  async onModuleInit() {
    console.log ('I can print! Yay!')
  }
}
```

srvE2.ts

```
export class SrvE2 implements OnModuleInit {
  constructor(
    private srvA: SrvA,
    private srvB: SrvB,
    private srvC: SrvC,
    private srvD: SrvD,
  ) {}

  async onModuleInit() {
    console.log ('I refuse to print so long as SrvD is here. Comment it and I will             
    print')
  }
}
```

srvE.module.ts

```
@Module({
  import: [SrvD], // the module
  providers: [SrvE1, SrvE2], // the services
  exports: [SrvE1, SrvE2],
})
```

Comment: 1) `SrvD` shouldn't be in the `imports`, its module should be there instead. 2) is `SrvD` `REQUEST` scoped?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel the `SrvD` in imports is the module. Sorry I'm not sure I understand what `SrvD` `REQUEST` means.

Comment: Does `SrvD` inject `REQUEST` or anything else that injects `REQUEST`?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel yes! `SrvC` does inject `REQUEST`.

Comment: @JayMcDoniel Ok I'm not sure in this excerpt, it may not be `SrvC` but when I deep dive into the services within the one causing the issue, REQUEST has been injected there.

Comment: @JayMcDoniel I see from the documentation that this is the expected behaviour when it is request scoped. But now I'm lost on how to get around that.

Comment: I had the same problem. Then I found that an exception occurs in one of the OnInitModule methods, which stops the other OnInitModule methods from firing.
Use try catch in all OnInitModule methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Request scoped providers spread this scope to whole chain of injection. Consequently, if you use it, even deeply inside your code, then `onModuleInit` won't run.

That being said, well ... request scope isn't very recommended, performance wise. Here is an interesting article : [Why You Should Avoid Using Request-scoped Injection in NestJS](https://guxi.me/posts/why-you-should-avoid-using-request-scope-injection-in-nest-js/)

I've also bumped into this question & its answers : [How to inject a request scoped provider at NestJS controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59681572/how-to-inject-a-request-scoped-provider-at-nestjs-controller)

I've tried `nj-request-scope` package from @profes, and it works fine, especially to fix your problem.

If you don't want to use it, you can still try to move your `onModuleInit` code in a default scoped service.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running hybrid apps or any microservice at all without the `Scope.REQUEST`, you add this after create your nest app;

```js
...
app.init()
...
```

Check here for more, https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/410

Answer (score 0):

I am dealing with a similar issue. Based on the comments here I tried changing the scoping for my new dependency from `Scope.REQUEST` to `Scope.DEFAULT` and that resolved my issue.